# "unexpected end of file" - what might be wrong with my code?

Tags: shell, command

I am trying to write the shell script to download EarthData from the EOSDIS worldview. Can anyone please tell me why it is showing "**data: invalid option --v**" all the time? Here is the code:

```
set inp = 1
set reg = 1

set year = 2020
 
 
#set jul_day = `date +"%j"`
set jul_day=152

set i=205

while ($i>33)

set query_day=`date -v -"$i"d +"%Y-%m-%d"`
echo $query_day
echo $jul_day

if ($inp == 1) then
   set n1 = 'MODIS_Terra'
   set out1 = '.terra.250m.tif'
        else if ( $inp == 2 ) then
            set n1 = 'MODIS_Aqua'
            set out1 = '.aqua.250m.tif'
                else if ( $inp == 3 ) then
                    set n1 = 'VIIRS_SNPP'
                    set out1 = '.viirs.250m.tif'
endif


set t1 = 'https://wvs.earthdata.nasa.gov/api/v1/snapshot'
set t1a = 'REQUEST=GetSnapshot&TIME='

if ( $reg == 1 ) then
# NE Greenland
 set t2 = 'T00:00:00Z&BBOX=200704,-2009088,1093632,-317440&CRS=EPSG:3413&LAYERS='
 set t3 = '_CorrectedReflectance_TrueColor,Coastlines&WRAP=day,x&FORMAT=image/tiff&WIDTH=4458&HEIGHT=8120'
 set out_f = ' Fram_Strait'

endif


set saug = $t1a$query_day$t2$n1$t3
echo $saug
set writ = $out_f$year$jul_day$out1

wget  --no-check-certificate --glob=on $t1'?'$saug  --output-document=$writ


@ jul_day ++
@ i --
end
```

This code runs entirely fine in MacBook (Linux). However, when I try it with my windows, I only get an unexpected error. Can anyone please help me with it?

Comment: Linux systems generally use the GNU version of `date` which does not support the `-v` option. I believe OS X (which is not linux) uses a BSD-derived version of `date` which does support `-v`. For portability, you need to only use options that are defined in [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html) (which is basically nothing except the format string...)

Comment: This is a csh script that must be run with csh. If you try to run it with bash, you will get "unexpected end of file".

Comment: @AshfaqAhmed: Why are you tagging this with _shell_, if it is not a POSIX shell script? Also, specify which csh implementation you are using on Windows. I remember that long time ago, there was a tcsh for Windows which was pretty buggy, and I would recommend agains using it.

Comment: @thatotherguy how can I 1) make it a Bash script? or 2) how can I run this csh script in my windows command prompt? I have just started learning this only3 days ago. Can you please help me out here?

Comment: @jhnc can you kindly tell me what should I write in the -v part of this:

 set query_day=`date -v -"$i"d +"%Y-%m-%d"` 

line?

Comment: @AshfaqAhmed 1. Bash is a different language with different syntax, so you would have to look up a Bash tutorial and rewrite the script from scratch in that language. 2. You can install csh (or tcsh) on Windows with e.g. WSL or Cygwin

Comment: @thatotherguy thank you! I have installed the Cygwin software. Let's see if I can make it this time. If it works now, I will be really grateful to you :)